# How do we know we believe things?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-religion

This is my first philosophy question, so please bear with me.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief) says belief is

> Belief is the state of mind in which a person thinks something to be the case, with or without there being empirical evidence to prove that something is the case with factual certainty.

When we believe something, how do we *know* we believe it? For example, let's say I believe that there is a keyboard I'm typing on right now. Even though I may not have complete justification for it, I still believe it. But how do I know I believe it? The definition of belief is "an acceptance that a statement is true or that something exists.". How do I know I accept something? You could say something like "because I accept it", but that doesn't really answer the question (how do you know you accept it?).

I know this question sounds a little stupid, but I can't seem to really find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The key concept is "state of mind"; see [Consciousness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're focusing on how we know that we believe something? Your main issue seems to be about the nature of knowledge -- no the specific type of content. If anything, knowing that we believe something is easier than knowing something about the external world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ned Block makes a distinction between mental states which he calls "P-conscious" and those which he calls "A-conscious." The former includes what one normally thinks of as "what-it's-like" phenomenology such as colors, sounds, tastes, etc. The second category is a different type of consciousness which includes beliefs and similar mental states:

> "The paradigm P-conscious states are sensations, whereas the paradigm
>   A-conscious states are 'propositional attitude' states like thoughts,
>   beliefs, and desires, states with representational content expressed
>   by 'that' clauses." Ned Block ("On a confusion about a function of
>   consciousness")

The term *A-conscious* derives from the fact that Block speaks of these mental states as "access consciousness." They are characterized as such because we access them for the rational control of thoughts and actions.

Since beliefs are mental states which make up our consciousness, we know we believe because we experience it in a similar way that we experience thoughts and desires. Visual experience, for example, is usually accompanied by a belief or certainty that what we are seeing is real. That sense of certainty is *a-consciousness* accompanying the phenomenal experience of vision. We know it because we experience it in a qualitative way. It's a certain sense of presence that we become aware of in our interaction with objective reality.

Answer (score 2):

The answer isn't in what you think, it's in what you do. How do you know you believe a keyboard is in front of you and produces letters when you type with it? It's because you interact with the keyboard as if that were true. Similarly, once you've come to know other objects based on certain criteria, you will interact with them based on your belief (understanding) of them.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the quick answer too. In terms of religion, believing in God, let's say, would mean doing things like good works and praying, correct? That's how you "believe" in God; not by just mentally saying "I believe", but actually doing what you would if it *were* true. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, what would you say to "how do I know I'm interacting with the keyboard"? A possible answer might be "because what I'm doing is *by definition* interacting with a keyboard".

Comment: Yea, belief in God represents an ontological belief about the universe. If you were say, a Christian, and your understanding of the universe was based on Christian beliefs, you would interact with the world in that way.

Comment: "How do I know I'm interacting with a keyboard?"... how do I know I just threw a rock through a window? The rock just went through the window and the glass smashed.

Comment: @CanadianCoder all sorts of people believe in God, but act otherwise.

Comment: Maybe they don't actually believe in God? Or sincerely believe that they will suffer consequences from refuting God?

Comment: I don't mean to sound annoying or anything, but how would you know the rock went through the window?

Comment: Many would raise the stakes here and say that the action has to be without reservation, apology or calculated risk, otherwise you only 'entertain the belief' and do not hold it.  E.g. Sinning does not prove you disbelieve in God, because you do so with apology (by which I don't mean "I am sorry", I mean an ad hoc rationalization or justification).  Whatever you say to yourself, you don't actually believe it is safe and acceptable to be gay if you act upon this belief by sneaking around and hiding your actions due to calculations of risk.

Comment: You know you believe because you act as if it were true, but how do you act as if it were true? Because you know you believe?

Comment: This answer is what would be called a pragmatic account of knowledge. It could probably be improved with references. (or to use a different vocabulary know-that vs. know how).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't actually know anything about philosophy proper, though, it's just me brain ;)

Answer (score 0):

You believe in such a thing cause you value it. Even though you can’t see it, you can feel it. You can’t see oxygen, but you BELIEVE you are inhaling it with each breath you take if not not you know you’ll die! You can’t see the wind, but you can feel it. You can’t see Wifi, but you Believe it exist cause you either have bars on your phone for indication or you see the green lights on your modem. Everything you can’t see can be proven by the things you can see! Believing is seeing not seeing to believe!T-Lynn!!

Answer (score -1):

My definition of belief is that I can prove it to myself. Regardless of the quality of who accepts the proof as true seems to be the case that if I can't prove it I can't believe it. There's the reality that we humam beings can trick other's into thinking that we believe something while there's no real conviction if no *true* proof is present. That's just **pretending** to believe. There's something called lying as we all know.

Comment: This answer could use some sourcing. As written, it's just a raw opinion that doesn't demonstrate knowledge of work on the subject.